# What is the purpose of being able to set a time at a unrealistic point of time?

Tags: time, clock

When fiddling around with the time settings on Windows, I noticed that you can set the date at an unrealistic point in history.

**Why is this possible and what's its purpose?** Did Microsoft and other companies expect someone to go back in time to use their computer? I understand the purpose of perhaps far into the future if our advanced civilization happens to discover our modern technology, *but why the past?*

It's not just computers. You can also do this on cell phones or video game consoles, etc.

[image]

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Why would you need to change the system time to access old files?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Windows 10 only goes back as far as 1988. I'm sure with other operating systems, you can set that time even further back.

Comment: As a developer for things that sometimes include year-selections like these, I do it simply because everyone else does it. It would just feel weird if the only year in a 2018 software you could select was 2018 (and newer). I usually go back to [1970](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/why-does-unix-time-start-at-1970-01-01) though, since that's when UNIX time starts. I'm sure that some people have use-cases for it, as in modification dates on files or making application X believe it's a specific date today.

Comment: Because it ***is*** 1988!

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Then that means.... _(fades out of existance)_

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, being primary opinion based. We can't give a definite answer on why various companies had the decision to allow selection of year back in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it takes more lines of code to limit the range of years and there is no benefit to do this thing.
Therefore, why should they do that?

Comment: What would be the difference in the range in the code if that was the case?

Comment: You won't know exactly when will that library using this piece of code been put into production and release to public. Is it 2016? 2017? 2018? 2xxx? So I guess they just randomly select a time that date back several decades. I saw many set as 1900 but not sure why they use 1988.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to *set* the date, that implies that the current information the system has about the date is wrong.

So you don't know the exact date. Given that, you should limiting it to reasonable period work?

Your clock may have a glitch, and may say "today we have the year 2050". If you limit the year you can set, to, say, 10 years ago, you won't be able to set the correct year.

This makes for angry users, cursing the developers. So it makes much more sense to allow the user to set the complete range, if even if some of it is long ago.

That the minimum date is in the 80s has to do with the way the time is represented internally (usually as seconds since a certain date, when the OS was made).

Comment: I think the question is not about "10 years ago" or so. It's about OS-es *released* in 21st century that allow to set the year 1988 as current. There's no way someone could use them in 1988.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: So you want someone to adjust the minimal date that can be set according to the release date of the current OS patch? A lot of effort for something that doesn't hurt anyone...

Comment: I know. My point is your reasoning "I don't know the exact date, so I allow any date" doesn't apply here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: You can probably come up with various lower bounds, but why disallow them? If you disallow stuff unnecessarily, there's always be some kind of situation you didn't foresee when the lower bound you thought *must* apply in fact didn't. So, don't do it.

Comment: Neither I want to disallow them nor I want others to disallow them. I would allow users to set their date wrong. I criticize your reasoning: "If you need to set the date, that implies that the current information the system has about the date is wrong. So you don't know the exact date." But if you're releasing the OS *now* you can be sure 1988 will never be correct. So if you care about the date being correct you *could* disallow 1988 because it's *wrong* for sure. Correctness may be the reason to disallow it, not to allow it.